# Namespace without exported members, vs IIFE

Tags: typescript

If there are no `export`ed members within a namespace, and no need to merge the namespace somewhere else, is there any benefit to this:

```
namespace Dummy {
    //code here
}
```

over this:

```
(() => {
    //code here
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IIFE leaves one less thing in the global scope (the namespace leaves exactly one thing in the global scope), so if you don't want the things touched, the IIFE is the cleanest solution.

There is an interesting parallel to bear in mind though, which is the `sealed` keyword in C#... using `sealed` on a class prevents it from being sub-classed. In quite a lot of places where it is used, there are lots of complaints about how it makes it hard to extend behaviour. If your code is part of a library, you may want to consider whether you want to absolutely hide your `Dummy` in an IIFE, or whether someone may want to extend or merge its contents - but it is of course your choice entirely based on your specific context.